# How to post code snippet in comments section in stack overflow

Tags: fonts, formatting, format, comments, pretty-print

I have to comment a piece of code in comment section. lets say 10 lines of code. how do I comment it in proper formatting. please tell me the trick. thanks in advance

Comment: [Can you put code snippets in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92332/can-you-put-code-snippets-in-comments)